# Show that the function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous at $x=0$ but not differentiable at $x=0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, continuity

Show that the function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by 
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
    0,& \text{if } ~x=0 \\
    \frac{x}{1+e^{1/x}}, &   x\ne 0.         
\end{cases} $$
is continuous at $x=0$ but not differentiable at $x=0$.

Please help me.

$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0+}\frac{x}{1+e^{1/x}}=?$

$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0-}\frac{x}{1+e^{1/x}}=?$

$Rf'(0)=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0+}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0+}\frac{1}{1+e^{1/h}}=?$

$Lf'(0)=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0-}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0-}\frac{1}{1+e^{1/h}}=?$

Answer (score 3):

Hint: prove that
$$
\lim_{h\to0^-}e^{1/h}=0,
\qquad
\lim_{h\to0^+}e^{1/h}=\infty
$$

Comment: Yes, I know, but please help me find those.

Comment: @user1942348 Apply the well known $\lim_{t\to-\infty}e^t=0$, $\lim_{t\to\infty}e^t=\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Continuity at $x=0$:

Since $e^{1/x}>0$  for all $x$ we have:

$0 \le |f(x)|=\frac{|x|}{1+e^{1/x}} \le |x|$ for all $x \ne 0$

Comment: @Ered ok, great. Hope you suggest sandwich theorem next. what next to find f'(x)